# Upgrade PHP only

Tags: package-management, php

I am using PHP Version 5.4.45 and want to upgrade to PHP 5.5.

I tried to upgrade with `sudo apt-get install php5`.

But after the install i still have PHP Version 5.4.45. Of course i restarted the webserver after the installation. I need to upgrade because Typo3 needs at least PHP Version 5.5.

Is there a way to only upgrade PHP to a higher version without having to upgrade other software like apache?

Comment: Which linux distribution do you use, and in what version?

Comment: I use Debian 4.9.2-10

Comment: Thanks. I found a working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29201696/4684797

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" or similar things to your question. If you want to be super helpful, post the solution you found as an answer and accept it instead.

Comment: Why should i repost an existing answer?

Comment: StackExchange's policy is to avoid links to solutions or answers (as links may become stale) and write the solution in full so all questions and answers are self-contained. I've posted the answer for you.

Comment: @EdwardBlack because it isn't an existing answer. It's an answer on another site, not here. The Stack Exchange sites are all independent. They are also string question and answer sites so if there is no answer posted, the question will remain marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29201696/4684797 , as indicated by the OP, with a lot of noise removed):

```
 sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add these lines at the end of the file:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```

Then do

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```